# Spotlight index breaks after reboot

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

After each reboot, my Spotlight index seems to break and I only get Dictionary results. I then have to rebuild the index (like add/remove root / to that list in the system preferences for spotlight) and it works fine until reboot. After reboot the same problem appears again.

I think my index first "crashed" after inserting my USB key, but it might only be a coincidence... I think I removed the USB key (iirc via Eject) before Spotlight has indexed it. I am not sure if this is relevant. I have not used my USB key since then, but the problem persists. I am not using any external drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this issue, registered an account just to post how I fixed it because there's so much crap on the net and most are half-arsed answers.

So yeah, my Spotlight broke after every single time I rebooted. So I had to rebuild the index every single time.

This is what I did, in the order I did it;

```
sudo diskutil repairPermissions /
```

I repaired all the disk permissions, seeing as apparently that's what causes it most of the time. Then I rebooted into single user mode (Command-S while booting) and put in

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
```

The check came back ok.

Then I entered 'reboot' to reboot the computer and logged back in.

Then I completely nuked Spotlight by;

```
sudo rm -r /.Spotlight*

sudo rm -r /Library/Spotlight

sudo mdutil -i off /

sudo mdutil -i on /
```

Then I restarted and logged back in. After this, Spotlight started indexing everything. I also opened up Console (Applications -> Utilities). Select "All messages" under Database Searches on the left. I searched for "mds" and "mdworker" while it was indexing, refreshing it every now and then. I found one file it had errors on, the message was;

```
Mar 15 16:02:48 CAPTAIN-JEWs-MacBook-Pro /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdworker[558]: FontImporter: Validation failed - "/Users/jewishjews/Public/World of Warcraft/Interface/AddOns/MikScrollingBattleText/Fonts/cooline.ttf".
```

So I deleted that file. Actually I deleted all of WoW because I don't play shitty games anymore. Moving on...

I had activity monitor open the entire time. I was watching the activity of mdworker and mdworker32 (indexing processes). At one point mdworker was sitting on 0% activity, then I checked the indexing progress of Spotlight. It was stuck about 3/4 of the way through, and the time was just increasing, up to about 9 hours. After awhile I got fed up and reset the computer.

After it rebooted I checked again and it was stuck on calculating the time remaining. mdworker wasn't running in activity monitor either. I checked online and some people were going on about md5 failing to hash things, which is why mdworker wasn't running. I couldn't find anything related to it in the Console logs though.

At that point I had to leave, so I just shut the computer down for about an hour. When I got home I booted it up and it started indexing again, and mdworker was running fine. Weird. It finished, and Spotlight was working fine.

Then I decided to reboot, seeing as I lose Spotlight functionality after a reboot. I logged back in and ... it worked fine. I decided to try booting into Bootcamp and then back into OS X to see if that is what messes my indexes up.

So I did that, came back. Then Spotlight wasn't working again, only giving me dictionary results as usual. SHIT. I had the bright idea that I could try removing Bootcamp from Spotlight indexing. I wasn't sure if it would even index it, but I have NTFS Fuse, so it was a possibility.

So I clicked the Spotlight button, searched for something then clicked Spotlight Preferences. Then I went to privacy and added the Bootcamp volume. Then I closed it and tried Spotlight again, and the damn thing worked. So I rebooted. Stopped working. I added Bootcamp to privacy again. It worked again. What the hell?

I rebooted again and tried it again. I searched for Firefox, and nothing came up. So I decided to click Spotlight Preferences again. I saw that the second I clicked Spotlight Preferences it gave me results for the split-second that the Spotlight window is open for before it closes and System Preferences opens. So it seems that adding Bootcamp wasn't what did it.

So I rebooted. Searched, got nothing. Clicked Spotlight Preferences, closed it then searched again. The stupid thing works. I then tried booting back into Bootcamp to see if that would destroy it. I logged back in and Spotlight works without me having to do the Spotlight Preferences trick. I've rebooted/shut down about 15 times so far and so far it is working perfectly.

So yeah, that's how I fixed it. It's still working so for now it's fixed...

Sorry for the rather verbose reply. I just detest people who give really shitty replies or say "dw i fixed it lol" 2 weeks later. Considering the computer-voodoo I had to go through to get it working, I figured I'd say everything I did because to be honest I have NO clue what exactly fixed the evil temptress that is Spotlight.

Comment: There should be a quicker way I guess ?

Comment: Thank you for your extensive reply!

Comment: after all that…  you basically breeze over… what the actual fix is.  it's somewhere in those last four paragraphs, but i'm not sure if you attribute the fix to voodoo (which should't be posted here) or if there is a concrete "step" that you say "fixes" "it".  needs clarification, or some boldfaced demarcation, or something…  no one needs to read your life story and still wonder how or why they can't search files on their computer…  also, this post should have been migrated to superuser, or ask different.

Comment: Where solution?